# The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: c++

Could you guys tell me why a simple c++ file can't work and gives me errors in the terminal.Is it a simple error? Thank you.The photo is on the link:

[image]

Comment: The shell doesn't find your c++ compiler, did you setup the `%PATH%` environment variable properly?

Comment: I looked around to what people are saying,they said to 
You have to add mingw.First, find out if you have installed g++ and find where it is located..But I have no idea what %PATH% environment variable is and how to add mingw,even when I looked at the instructions.

Comment: ***what %PATH% environment variable is*** It's important to know about this environment variable of your OS for `c++`  programming. [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and [https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: @SimonBarazinsky you probably need to get familiar with these terms before proceeding: _IDE_, _toolchain_, _operating system_, _development environment_. There's plethora of good tutorials on the internet, no need to ask here,  which should be your last resort, but coming with some basic research and knowledge of what's actually going on.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking `g++` in Windows. You must guarantee that this compiler and the relevant development tools are installed and configured correctly first.

These are the prerequisites before you start to use them:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_prerequisites

You can refer to:

- Instructions on the [MSYS2 website](https://www.msys2.org/) to install Mingw-w64.
- VSCode tutorial [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), this is quite clear, for example [prerequisites](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_prerequisites) point 4 tells you how to add the path to your `Mingw-w64` bin folder to the Windows `PATH` environment variable carefully.